# Installing OS X Yosemite from compressed DMG file in VMware Fusion

Tags: vmware, dmg

I would like to install OS X Yosemite in VMware Fusion 7.0.

If I select the DMG file my university is providing, VMware is unable to boot from the DMG file.

The image is a compressed DMG.

```
Properties:
    Encrypted: false
    Kernel Compatible: true
    Checksummed: true
    Software License Agreement: false
    Partitioned: false
    Compressed: true
```

Is there a way to make VMware Fusion boot from a compressed DMG?

I tried to convert to DMG to "uncompressed" or ISO with no improvement. I always get:

```
EFI VMware Virtual IDE CDROM Drive (IDE 1.0) ... unsuccessful
```

In the VMware log file I only see:

```
2015-08-12T09:44:42.586+01:00| vcpu-0| I120: CDROM: Connecting sata0:1 to '/Users/corti/Downloads/Yosemite (uncompressed).dmg'. type=2 remote=0
2015-08-12T09:44:42.587+01:00| vcpu-0| I120: CDROM: Checking initial physical media state...
2015-08-12T09:44:42.587+01:00| vcpu-0| I120: CDROM:  initial physical CDROM state is 1 (sense)
```

Comment: How did you convert it to uncompressed? Using `hdiutil convert` is the best option. I assume the DMG your university provided is actually bootable - have you tried booting it on real hardware?

Comment: Did not try to boot with is as I do not have a physical CD-ROM. Is there another way to check if the image is bootable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter what type the DMG is as VMware Fusion cannot install OS X Yosemite by booting it or even booting the Install OS X Yosemite.app downloaded from Apple as that's not how it works in VMware Fusion.  VMware Fusion must first make an Installer Image from the Install OS X Yosemite.app and install from the Image it creates.

Have a look at: [Installing OS X 10.10 Yosemite as a guest operating system in VMware Fusion (2082109)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2082109).

> To install Mac OS X 10.10 in a virtual machine using the Yosemite app
>   download:
>
> 1. Select **File > New** from the Fusion menu bar.
> 2. Select **Install from disc or image** and click **Continue**.
> 3. Drag and drop the **Install OS X Yosemite** application into **Use operating system installation disc or image** dialog box.
> 4. Click **Continue**.
> 5. Fusion should automatically discover the Guest Operating System. If not, ensure that the Operating System is set to **Apple Mac OS X** and
>      that the version is set to **Mac OS X 10.10.** Click **Continue**.
> 6. If you want to modify any of the settings, such as memory (RAM), CPU, or hard disk size, click **Customize Settings** and specify the
>      non-default values.
> 7. Click **Finish**. The installation starts.
> 8. When prompted, select **Reinstall Mac OS X** and click **Continue**.
> 9. Click **Continue**.
> 10. Agree to the license agreement and follow the prompts to begin the installation.
>
> After the installation completes, you must install VMware Tools on the
>   virtual machine. To do this, first eject the Mac OS installation disc
>   image from within the new virtual machine. For more information, see 
>   [Installing VMware Tools in a Mac OS Guest
>   (1032440)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1032440).

Comment: What if you don't have the .app file?  Can you drag and drop the .pkg or .dmg file?

Answer (score 4):

The solution from @user3439894 did not worked for me while installing OS X 10.11 El Capitan using a dmg file. I created a bootable ISO to install it on VMware Fusion 8.0.1 by following the below steps as advised [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-create-el-capitan-os-x-bootable-dvd.1923894/page-2#post-22064565).

```
# Mount the installer image
hdiutil attach /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_app

# Create a ElCapitan blank ISO image of 9900mb with a Single Partition - Apple Partition Map
hdiutil create -o /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr -size 9900m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J

# Mount the ElCapitan blank ISO image
hdiutil attach /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build

# Restore the Base System into the ElCapitan blank ISO image
asr restore -source /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg -target /Volumes/install_build -noprompt -noverify -erase

# Remove Package link and replace with actual files
rm /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/Packages
cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/Packages /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/

# Copy El Capitan installer dependencies
cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.chunklist /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/BaseSystem.chunklist
cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/BaseSystem.dmg

# Unmount the installer image
hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_app

# Unmount the ElCapitan ISO Image
hdiutil detach /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/

# Create a sparseimage and auto-size it
hdiutil convert /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr.dmg -format UDSP -o /tmp/ElCapitan
hdiutil resize -size `hdiutil resize -limits /tmp/ElCapitan.sparseimage | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'`b /tmp/ElCapitan.sparseimage

# Convert the ElCapitan sparseimage to ISO/CD master
hdiutil convert /tmp/ElCapitan.sparseimage -format UDTO -o /tmp/ElCapitan

# Remove the unwanted images
rm /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr.dmg
rm /tmp/ElCapitan.sparseimage

# Rename the ElCapitan ISO image and move it to the desktop
mv /tmp/ElCapitan.cdr ~/Desktop/ElCapitan.iso
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am sorry, I didn't knew this, will keep this in mind in future. I've edited my answer now. Please remove the negative mark now :). Thanks